# Wordpress get current post term parent by child ID

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

In page I have ID of term child, I need find out this child parent by child ID, it's passible, maybe someone can help with this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what the [`get_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) function is for:

```
$term_id = 21; // Lucky number :)

$child_term = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );
$parent_term = get_term( $child_term->parent, 'category' );
```

Replace `'category'` with whatever taxonomy you're using.

Comment: Thaks, please edit not `$term->parent` but `$child_term->parent`

Answer (score 3):

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id , 'product_cat');
if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $term = get_term_by("id", $term->parent, "product_cat");
        if ($term->parent > 0) {
            $term = get_term_by("id", $term->parent, "product_cat");
        }
        $cat_obj = get_term($term->term_id, 'product_cat');
        $cat_name = $cat_obj->name;
    }
}
echo '<br />('. $cat_name . ')';
```